# How to make an html image input and then run a python algorithm on it(for a website)?

Tags: html, python-3.x

I am hoping to make a website in which the user inputs an image and then I run an algorithm on it, how would I do that?

Comment: It is way too broad. You need to break it into parts. Seems like a simple html form with a file input and you upload it.

Comment: upload it to where?(sorry im a bit of a noob).

Comment: Well you said python so I assume your python script that lives on the server. It is a basic form submission. Plenty of tutorials on uploading images.